# How to create ISU user with required permissions in the Workday

Tags: workday-api

I want to create a ISU user in the workday to use the user while requesting data using API. I want to get workers information and need to change the business title of a worker. So, also please share the required permission that I need to give to the ISU user while creating in the workday. How can I check that my ISU user has the required permissions for sending a request.

Thanks,

I got the username, password, tenant and URL. I used the username and password for the authentication. What I am missing that I have not properly created ISU user.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "View Security for Securable Item" task, you can search for the Web Services you are trying to use, and you can "View Security". You will need to add your ISSG there.

If you are using any Business Processes, you will also need to edit the Business Process Policy to allow your ISSG to Initiate the Web Service for it.